# Encapsulate XML inside JAR

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

I know this question has been [asked quite a lot](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=xml%20inside%20jar) on the internet, but I get stuck in the process.

The problem:

I got some XML files (OpenStreetMap – .osm) that I need to parse. My method to parse these OSM files is as follows: (edit—this method sets the OSMHandler as my ContentHandler and the actual parsing is taking place in that class)

```
void parseOSM(String filename) {
    try {
        XMLReader reader =
                XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(
                new OSMHandler()); //extends DefaultHandler
        reader.parse(filename);
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This works fine when you run the application inside IntelliJ, but now I need to make a .jar that will run on simple double click.

To my understanding we need to get the OSM file as a ressource, something like:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

I'm not quite sure how I ask my OSMHandler to parse this InputStream since the parse method only accepts a String. Can anyone elaborate on what do to from here?

**EDIT**

I did try the following:

```
void parseOSM_jar(String filename){
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(is);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem here is that it doesn't call/set my OSMHandler class as the "parser" as far as I'm concerned.

**FINAL EDIT**

It works now, thanks to simple tip by. I simply use InputSource as follows:

```
void parseOSM(String filename) throws ParserConfigurationException {

    InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    InputSource input = new InputSource(stream);

    try {
        XMLReader reader =
                XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(
                new OSMHandler());
        reader.parse(input);
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as You use the XMLReader it can parse InputStream http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)

Comment: Doesn't your link say InputSource?

Comment: It works! You are absolutely right. I'm editing my post with the final, working code chunk. Thanks!